# How can I check if a string contains (number)

Tags: java, regex

I need to test if a string contains brackets with a number in the middle

Fight Club (2008) -> true

Sick (Documentary 2008) -> false

I have this but i cant test it because I can;t compile. I get an error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )"

```
if(title.matches("\\((\d)\\)")){

}
```

Comment: Should you be double escaping the brackets? I would have thought `"\([\d]+\)"` would be sufficient...

Comment: @SO One backslash is for the regex escape, and the other is for the Java string escape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
if(title.matches(".*?\\(\\d+\\).*")){

}
```

Remember that `String#matches` expects to match complete input.

Comment: Is there a reason you need the capturing group? (Why `\\((\\d+)\\)` instead of `\\(\\d+\\)`?)

Comment: Yes removed it, since it is not really needed.